# Why is DataFrame changing the datatype of all input into objects?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, series

I pass numpy array and pd.Series with different data types, text, int, and floats into pd.DataFrame and the output is a DataFrame with all object datatypes. Why does it do that and is there anything I can do to preserve the original datatypes?

```
pd.DataFrame(np.c_[X, TotalSF, TotalBaths, HasFire], columns=(list(X.columns) + ['TotalSF', 'TotalBaths', 'HasFire']))
```

X is a 2-D array with some values as text and some as number.
TotalSF, TotalBaths, and HasFire are pandas Series with numbers as values.

Comment: Note that the datatype of a dataframe column (or series) will only be float if all rows in the column or series are floats.  Similar for integer dtypes.  Basically if even one row of a series is a string/object then the datatype of the whole column will be object.

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe workس with general datatypes, if you want to change your dataframe data type use

```
pandas.DataFrame.astype(target type)
```

track below code with and without astype method:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[["red", "apple"], ["yellow", "orange"], ["blue", "banana"], ["green", "avocado"]],
                    columns=["color", "fruitN"])
# data = data.set_index("fruitN")
file_1 = ["akee", "apricot", "avocado"]
file_2 = ["avocado", "bilberry", "banana", "blackberry"]
file_3 = ["blackberry", "coconut", "cranberry"]
file_1_df = pd.DataFrame(data=file_1, columns=["type_1"])
file_2_df = pd.DataFrame(data=file_2, columns=["type_2"])
file_3_df = pd.DataFrame(data=file_3, columns=["type_3"])
l = [file_1_df, file_2_df, file_3_df]
for x, y in enumerate(l):
    data['c' + str(x + 1)] = data.fruitN.isin(y.iloc[:, 0].tolist()).astype(int)

data = data["c2"].astype(int)
print(data)
```